# Datepicker is not working by using JavaScript executer

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I tried to pick date in spicejet website but not my code is not working. as its not selecting my given value. Although I'm not getting any error form my code. Can anyone please help me.
Here is the code.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class HandleCalendarByJS {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        
        WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"main-container\"]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]"));
        String datevalue= "Tue, 06 Jun 2023";
        selectDateByJS(driver, element, datevalue);
        
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.close();
        
        
        
    }
    public static void selectDateByJS(WebDriver driver, WebElement element, String datevalue) {
        JavascriptExecutor js= ((JavascriptExecutor)driver);
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+datevalue+"');", element);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, below code will select 06-Jun-2023 from the Departure Date date picker.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        
        driver.get("https://www.spicejet.com/");
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[text()='Departure Date']//following::div[2]"))).click();
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("(//div[@data-testid='undefined-calendar-day-6'])[1]"))).click();       
        
    }
```

**Imports required:**

```
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

**Result:**

[image]

### UPDATE:

 Not really sure why you want to use `JS` while selenium can do it. Anyway, using `JS` should be the last option as it won't imitate browser actions as Selenium does. Having said that, since you are specific about using `JavaScriptExecutor`, refer below code:

Change below line:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value','"+datevalue+"');", element);
```

To:

```
js.executeScript("arguments[0].innerText = arguments[1]", element, datevalue);
```

### Imp. Note:

 Please note that you cannot directly use `JavascriptExecutor` to enter text into a `<div>` node. It's not recommended to simulate direct text input into a `<div>` element using `JavascriptExecutor`. However, you can modify the `innerText` property of a  element using JavascriptExecutor to set its content to a specific text value. Please keep in mind that this may or will have adverse effects on the webpage.

Comment: HI @Shawn, Thanks for your reply, but I need to do it using JavascriptExecuter. If you can give tell me what is the problem in my code, that would be very helpful.

Comment: @Abhay - Check the updated answer and let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi @Shawn, that's worked totally fine. Could you please explain me the line you suggested. I appreciate you for helping me out :) .

Comment: Using the `innerText` property, we are trying to set the text value for the desired element. element is passed in argument 1 and the value to set is passed as argument 2. In simple words, we are updating the HTML from backend using javascript. The first answer using selenium is more like a front end action, and this answer using `JS` is backend action. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Abhay - If this answer was useful you can upvote it. And if you think this is the best solution you have got for the question you asked, you can accept it. This way the question is not left unanswered.